What is mukhe, pAdyoh and sarvAnge in mantra nyasa?
I'm specifically referrring to the nyasa of the Gopala sahasranama (from Sammohana tantra), although this one is there in many other mantras/sahasranamas/stotras in the rishi nyasa.
The given nyasa for this specific sahasranama is - Narada as the Rishi at the crown of the head, anushtup as the chandas (metre) at the mouth, Sri Gopala as the devata at the heart, kama bija at the anus (guhye), maya shakti at the feet, chandra kilaka throughout.
The issue here for me is primarily with the shakti and the kilaka -
maya shaktaye namah pAdyoh ||
chandrah kilakayai namah sarvAnge ||
What mudras am I supposed to use for this, and what parts do I touch? pAdyoh is obviously the feet, so do I touch the two feet with my hands with any specific mudra? Same goes for sarvAnge - how do I do apply the nyasa throughout my body?
For 'anushtup chandase namo mukhe', what mudra do I use and should I touch the lips, or am I to touch the tip of the nose above the lips?
More generally, are there any 'default' mudras which can be used for such stotras or mantras which do not specifically mention any mudra?

Nyasa is implanting god's limbs in our respective limbs .. mukhe (face), padayoh (feet), sarvange (all body) refer to the limbs where god particles are being implanted.

@Rickross yes I'm aware of that. But I'm confused about the mudras. Which ones am I to use?

See videos on how to do Anga Nyasa by Medhayoga on Youtune. Medhayoga is the name of the channel.
